# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib): shared object ‘rlang.so’ not found

Tags: r, tidyverse, rcpp, rlang

When trying to `library(tidyverse)` receiving variations on

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in 
library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib): shared object ‘rlang.so’ not found
```

A similar problem is [mentioned here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-fix-error-loading-tidyverse-library/41586)

Comment: What does this have to do with `Rcpp`?

Comment: @JosephWood see OP [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-fix-error-loading-tidyverse-library/41586)

Comment: Ahh, I see. I wonder if setting `dependencies = TRUE` would have solved your problem.

Comment: @JosephWood good suggestion, I tried that, and it didn't help. Same error persisted. I reinstalled rcpp, rlang, jsonlite, and after each installation a new package would appear in the error message. I also reinstalled R. But still `library(tidyverse)` failed. There is probably a better solution, but what worked (instantly) was to remove all the local libraries and start fresh with `install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies=T)` and it worked immediately. I have no idea why. I wouldn't have made this a SO question, except that the rstudio post doesn't allow comments after a certain time elapsed

Comment: You might want to file an issue with `tidyverse` team if you can come up with a reproducible example. These dependency chains can be really frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I kept reinstalling the package in the error message (e.g. `rlang` in error message in the question, but also `jsonlite` etc etc)

#### What worked

I deleted all existing libraries locally and simply reinstalled `tidyverse` and the others I needed, and the problem resolved entirely.

Comment: I recommend we delete the question and answer. This has been covered a million times.  _Across e.g. compiler changes_ (or other things that may affect the toolchain) you likely have to re-install components from the dependency graph.  It is a known C++ "feature".

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm having similar issues on another mac. Not exactly the same but similar. I think something happened when updating to R 3.6.1. Do you know if there's some sure fire way of fixing related issues? Starting at the root cause. E.g. reinstalling the whole dependency graph if possible? How would one go about that? Reinstall xcode? Or just update? Are there other programs that need updating?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel also, I notice the views on [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-fix-error-loading-tidyverse-library/41586) somewhat related issue have almost doubled in the past 3 weeks. For me at least, I have spent a few hours tinkering, and would much prefer to 'go nuclear' and just reinstall everything and know everything's as it ought to be, as to be honest, I don't understand the issues and if they're c++ / system issues I prefer to avoid them entirely rather than fumble my way through them :)